# Python: Get data from redis-pubsub, send to multiple users using websocket

Tags: python, websocket, redis, python-asyncio, publish-subscribe

My goal is to retrieve data from redis using pub-sub and then broadcast it to multiple users using websockets, however I can't get it to work using my knowledge of python and asyncio. So far, my code is the following:

```
import redis
import asyncio
import websockets

redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
channel = 'app:notifications'

connection = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(redis_url, decode_responses=True)

pubsub = connection.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=False)
pubsub.subscribe(channel)

async def listen():
    for item in pubsub.listen():
        message = item['data']
        if type(message) != int:
            print(message)
            yield message

async def server(websocket, path):
    while True:
        msg = await listen()
        websocket.send(msg)

start_server = websockets.serve(server, "localhost", 8000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Maybe I could have a pubsub coroutine running which sends the messages to all connected users, but I do not know how I could make that work. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.